# Add button to my View "Header/Title" bar

Tags: objective-c, ios4

In my AppDelegate, I create a UITabBarController and UINavigationController dynamically. I then add 3 views to it.

```
// Prepare the tab bar controller   
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

// Switch controller
UserSettingsController *settingsController = [[UserSettingsController alloc] init];

// Switches controller
SwitchesController *switchesController = [[SwitchesController alloc] init];

// Help controller
HelpController *helpController = [[HelpController alloc] init];

NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: switchesController, settingsController, helpController, nil];
tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers; 

if (self.navigationController == nil) {
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tabBarController];
}

[window addSubview:navigationController.view];
```

When I initially did this, I noticed that I now have a header/title bar at the top of my page. It's blank and really just takes up space. I'd like to utilize it though and add a "refresh" button to one of my views.

In the view I'm interested in, I attempted the following:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *refresh = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Refresh" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(refreshSwitches:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = refresh;
    [refresh release];
}

-(void)refresh{
    ...
}
```

No button showed up, so I'm either way off or I'm missing something.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Hard to say exactly whats going wrong from this code.  Could you perhaps show some more of your initialization code (for the views/nav controller)?  Also, have you confirmed that viewDidLoad is being called?

Comment: @Sam - yes, the viewDidLoad is being executed. I edited the post and added my init code for the views, tabBarController, navController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that your view controllers that you've added to the tabbar controller are not encapsulated by navigation controllers.  Although your UITabBarController has a navigation controller, this does not implicitly give all of its tabs navigation controllers (and without a nav controller, a view controller's `navigationItem` won't do anything.)  To remedy this problem I'd suggest encapsulating your view controllers with navigation controller upon initialization:

ex:

```
UserSettingsController *settingsController = [[UserSettingsController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:settingsController];
[settingsController release];

// etc...

NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navController, ..., ..., nil];
tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;

// Release your nav controllers, other cleanup
```

**EDIT**

Okay, I think I have a better idea of your setup now.  I was able to get the following to work:

```
self.tabBarController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = myButton;
```

An important caveat of this is that the button will persist on all of your tabbarcontroller's views unless you explicitly remove it.  This may prove annoying/inelegant to maintain, but I am not sure of another solution if the view you want to have the button is not directly associated to a nav controller itself.

Comment: This seems strange... my settingsController has "sub views" - I click on a row from my table and push a new view to the nav controller and it works... when I change to this method, I have two "bars" at the top until I remove the tabBars nav controller, but when I do that, I can no longer push views from my settingsController....

Comment: @Chu I edited my answer with another possible solution (which doesn't force you to give the views nav controllers.)